# How to partition drive for ZFS

Tags: linux, zfs, zpool

I'm trying to create a ZFS pool using the following command:

```
zpool create MyPool disk /dev/sda
```

However, I get the following error:

> cannot use '/dev/disk': must be a block device or regular file

I feel like I should have been able to find someone with this issue, but I haven't been able to. `/dev/sda` is a blank drive. Where am I going wrong? Do I have to format the drive before creating a zpool? If so, what format do I use?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a partition of a disk like /dev/sda1 (after fdisk-ing it).

Comment: What partition type do I use?

Comment: @mdpc Using partitions are supported, but certainly not a requirement. (The recommended method is to use whole disk.)

Comment: No partition is needed. The command you're using is incorrect.

Comment: @fukawi2 any idea where can i find the information about "using whole disk is recommended" any performance issues if partitions are used ?

Comment: @satch_boogie http://open-zfs.org/w/index.php?title=Performance_tuning&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile#Whole_Disks_versus_Partitions

Comment: @satch_boogie Heres an updated link. I see where says using whole disks is recommended but it doesn't say why. I'd like to know why bc coming from FreeBSD zfs, I've never heard of that recommendation.  https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zpoolconcepts.8.html?highlight=partition#Virtual_Devices_(vdevs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove "disk" from your command line. It's the cause of the error you're receiving.

```
zpool create MyPool sda
```

Comment: The man page says you should be able to specify the full path, but removing it made it work.

Comment: You can use the full path as well. It's not needed. The error here was using "disk".

Answer (score 2):

Try using this guide: [Aaron Topence - ZFS on Linux](https://pthree.org/2012/12/04/zfs-administration-part-i-vdevs/).

Assuming you are trying to create a zfs pool called MyPool, using /dev/sda as a disk, try:
    `# zpool create MyPool sda`

Answer (score 0):

As the marked answer indicates, the syntax is `zpool create <mount> <pool> [raidz(2|3)|mirror] <ids>`.

As a follow-on, it is [generally recommended](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ZFS#Identify_disks) to use disk IDs (using `ls -lh /dev/disk/by-id/`) to ensure continued correct identification of disks between restarts. This also helps physically identify disks when replacing them.